# If I try to scroll the tracker to adjust my position in the video... I can no longer playback the video unless I refresh the page

Tags: mediaelement.js

The videoplayer looses playback capability as soon as I try and use the sliding tracker bar. I'm using Google Chrome. I was testing out the player on the MediaElement website.

EDIT: This appears to be the same problem no matter what HTML5 player I try, so it's not just yours. I wonder why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have this problem. I think it was a problem with my browser (correct me if I was wrong). Glad it works now, though!